# Web Service in C# not showing all the methods available

Tags: c#, webmethod

I created a web service in C# but it is failing to show all the methods I created when I run the service.

Here is my code:

```
public class Data : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public Data()
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string getIPAddress()
    {
        return Context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public string getDateTime()
    {
        // gets the current date and time in the format Month/Day/Year Hour/Minute/Second
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:sszzz");
    }
}

<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Data.asmx.cs" Class="Learning_Team_A.Data" %>
```

It is only showing the getDateTime method on the page.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: You need to Right click in your service and update web service in visual studio and try